# Where to put Web API endpoints (urls) in an MVC 5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm helping create an MVC 5 web application. Its models are being provided via a Web API. Currently, the endpoints for the Web API are hard-coded into our controllers:

```
public HomeController() {
  string baseUrl = "http://webApi.example/api/";
  string endpoint1 = "endpoint1/{0}";
}
```

Obviously this is not the best approach. However, I'm not entirely sure where exactly we should put them. One of the challenges is the different environments the application will have to 'pass' through on its way to Production. For example, it must work 'as is' (with minimal configuration) in a development environment, QA, and ultimately production.

We've considered a few approaches, such as using the `Web.config` file. But that means we'd have to edit it in each and every environment ... and what if there's 30 development environments? Or 300? We've also considered reading things from the Windows Registry, under a special Key. This could be easily ported to all environments and supplied a 'generic' solution.

However, reading from the registry seems like bad idea (with no proof to tell me that it is or isn't).

So, what architect, strategy, or method could be used to create a valid configuration solution?

Comment: I considered posting this in a few other stack exchanges, but ultimately couldn't identify one that would be more suitable than SO. Please let me know if you think otherwise!

Comment: The web.config file is specifically for configuring settings for a given environment.  That is the appropriate location to put this if you expect it to be different for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a Web.config for development, beta and production for years.

You certainly could store the setting in the registry, although a Web.config would be easier (editing the registry seems like more of a hassle). The one benefit to using the registry is in the event of sensitive information (e.g. service account password).  This would allow the infrastructure team or server administrators to keep the password (registry key value) secret while letting developers deploy Web.config changes freely.  In your case it's just a simple URL so who cares?

Either way you're going to be storing the same number of values (either you have 30 different Web.config files or you have 30 different registry entries).  However, if you get to the point of having 30 different environments you're probably not going to be hand rolling these configuration entries.  You're probably at the scale of having continuous integration and deployments actually powered by software where the values would be dynamic based upon the deployment settings.

Comment: Picking up on the final point that @JustinHelgerson has made, I would suggest that you take a look at web config transformations at deployment time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx